# Can we use a common service without module into other module (specifically controller) in NestJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nestjs

I am working on a NestJs project. There are different modules. I want to have a common service without module that can b used anywhere in the app.
Is it possible to use a common service without module? If yes then how can i use it? Actually i want to use different functions from a service.

Comment: Why do you not want a module?

Answer (score 4):

if you want to use service term you need to register @Injectable() service to a module you can register it to app.module.ts, but it depends on what common.service.ts exactly do ?

if you want to use a dependency injection mechanism of Nestjs you should add @Injectable  and a Scope then register it into whatever module do you want.

if you got the answer plz vote me up :), if not leave a comment with more details